# Post Build event that zip files with timestamp in name

Tags: c#, visual-studio, post-build-event

I'm trying to make a post-build event that zip release files with a timestamp as a part of folder name.
I am creating zip file like this:

`if $(ConfigurationName) == Release (powershell Compress-Archive -Path '$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)' -DestinationPath '$(ProjectDir)bin\MyFile.zip' -Force)`

Now I have zip file named "MyFile.zip" but I want it to have date in its name, like "04.12.2020.MyFile.zip".

Does anyone have any idea how to do that?

Comment: Generally we call a script for our post build event and put the logic to perform whatever tasks are necessary in that script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using MSBuild property functions.

This is modified build step:

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug (powershell Compress-Archive -Path '$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)' -DestinationPath '$(ProjectDir)bin\MyFile_$([System.DateTime]::Now.Year)-$([System.DateTime]::Now.Month)-$([System.DateTime]::Now.Day).zip' -Force)
```

You can tweak it to have desired format.